# Kanji from an image

Tags: kanji, stroke-count

I'd appreciate it if anyone can give me directions on the meaning of this kanji:

How many strokes does it have?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's two kanji with 1 & 12 strokes (in that order).

Comment: thanks. the meaning? how many horizontal / vertical strokes?

Comment: I thought you only asked for the stroke count. Translation requests without any effort shown are considered off-topic. Do you recognize any other part of the kanji?

Comment: Sorry.

Is meaning 'Numer 1' or 'First'?

Comment: Yes, it means "number 1" or "first". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichiban